# How to prevent '#' from getting converted to '%23' in URL?

Tags: command, web, url

I'm trying to open a website at a specific location. The webpage is an HTML version of a markdown file, so appending a `#header` redirects straight to a location. It works when I do it manually in the browser but when I try to open the webpage at a specified `#header` from the terminal, the `#` gets transformed to a `%23` in the browser, which breaks the URL and thus the page:

```
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "http://localhost:8000/title#header"
```

How can I get the `#` to stay preserved as a `#` and not converted to `%23` ?

#### TL;DR

A webpage launched from terminal, via a URL containing a `#`, has the `#` character converted to `%23`. I want the `#` to stay a `#`. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome-cli open http://localhost:8000/title#header
```

This preserves the `#`.
Have fun

---

If you don't have `chrome-cli`, you can download it with:
`brew install chrome-cli`.